# Null check operator used on a null value in a stream builder, flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

im getting this exception when i load the page, it appear on display for a moment but when list is loaded it disappears. errors reads out line 255, att line 255 i have a child: streambuilder
i cannot figure out whats wrong

```
Expanded(
            child: StreamBuilder(
              stream: restaurants.where('status', isEqualTo: 'Approved').snapshots(),
              builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                return ListView(
                  children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((restaurants) {
                    return RestaurantCard(restaurants: restaurants,);
                  }).toList(),
                );
              },
            ),
          )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check for different statuses in `StreamBuilder`, and only build the `ListView` if there is data available:

```
StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
  stream: restaurants.where('status', isEqualTo: 'Approved').snapshots(),
   builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState ==
        ConnectionState.waiting) {
      return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    }
    if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return const Center(
        child: Text('Snapshot error'),
      );
    }
    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
      return const Center(
        child: Text('Snapshot data missing'),
      );
    }
    return ListView(
      children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((restaurants) {
        return RestaurantCard(restaurants: restaurants,);
      }).toList(),
     );
  })
```

Comment: i totally forgot that, thanks mate